# Bold some words from a dynamic string

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Fetching a string from a json file. but i want to bold some words in that sentence when displaying it in  tag here is my text code

```
<Text style={{
                fontSize: 16,
                lineHeight: 24,
                letterSpacing: 0.7,
                paddingRight: 20,
                fontWeight: "400"
              }}>{data3}</Text>
```

its a string `"Allowing Self-Employed applicants to qualify with NO Tax Returns."` and i want to bold "Self-Employed" in this string. please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

just use **replace**
and this should do the job even for multiple entities you can just loop it.

Edit:

as far as I understand from the snippet this is React Native
you can do almost the same with it.

replace with:

```
apiText.replace("text", <Text style={{**bold styles here**}}>text</Text>);
```

but don't forget to wrap the **apiText** inside  component

Comment: Do i have to write code like this? 
{data3.replace("Self-Employed", <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>text</Text>)}

Comment: you cane create it 1st like a variable to look more clean
const finalText = data3.replace("Self-Employed", <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Self-Employed</Text>

add <Text styles={{the styles for the rest of the text}}>{variable} </Text>

Comment: oh ok ok let me try it. please give me some time i will check and respond. thanks

Comment: did it       data3 = data3.replace("Self-Employed", <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Self-Employed</Text>);
output: "Allowing [object object] applicants to qualify with NO Tax Returns."

Answer (score -1):

In your CSS add:

```css
#myDIV {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

and change the string to:

```html
Allowing <span id="myDIV">Self-Employed</span> applicants to qualify with NO Tax Returns.
```

Comment: the example provided is React Native code